# Angular, Rxjs, catch exception thrown in the exception handling code

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, angular-unit-test

In this pseudo code example

```
this.someService.someMethod().subscribe(
  (data) =>
  {
      throw Exception
  }
  (err) =>
  {
      throw Exception
  }
```

How do I catch an error that is thrown inside the subscribe methods?

My specific scenario is that I want to write a unit test for a case that I know will throw an exception

I can't put try/catch logic inside the methods themselves, I want the catch inside the spec.ts file

Edit, just to repeat

**I can't put try/catch logic inside the methods themselves, I want the catch inside the spec.ts file**

Comment: You already have error block within subscribe method! does it not working?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the errors thrown by the error handling block using RxJS `catchError` operator twice like the following:

```js
this.someService
  .someMethod()
  .pipe(
    tap(data => {
      // do something here
      throw Exception;
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      throw Exception;
    }),
    catchError(err2 => {
      // do something with the error thrown from catchError, then return a new Observable
      return EMPTY;
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```